# Integrating Pivotal tracker with bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla, pivotaltracker

I am testing out bugzilla integration with pivotal tracker. I tried to associate a landfill installation. But I get there was a timeout while contacting the server. Is it possible to fix this ?? or Is it possible to integrate pivotal tracker with local installation of bugzilla?

Answer (score 0):

To integrate Pivotal and Bugzilla, you need your Bugzilla to be publicly available to the internet, as Pivotal backend server will try to connect to it from the "outside", not from your local PC.